# Flask config class

Tags: python, flask, import, configuration, importerror

I am trying to setup config classes for my project but i cant seem to figure out how to import them properly.

Project structure:

```
-project
  -instance
    -config.py
  -service
    -__init__.py
```

config.py:

```
class DefaultConfig(object):
    DEBUG = True

class ProductionConfig(DefaultConfig):
    DEBUG = False
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object('config.ProductionConfig')    
    return app
```

To run the app i did:

```
set FLASK_APP=service
set FLASK_ENV=production
FLASK run
```

While standing in the `project` folder

That gives me this error:

```
ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'config'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Debugged import:

- 'config' not found.

Original exception:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

My guess is that the path is not right. 
I followed [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/) example, where they talk about using inheritance for configuration and instance folders. It made alot of sense when i read it but i must have managed to missinterpret an integral part.

EDIT: Now it works. Instead of just

```
app.config.from_object('config.DefaultConfig')
```

i had to do

```
app.config.from_object('instance.config.DefaultConfig')
```

I think that is really confusing because setting the `instance_relative_config` to True like i did, should according to the docs set the path for the config files relative to the instance directory. Now i am accessing them relative to the project root...

Comment: Read carefully this section http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#development-production

Comment: @taras yeah, i read it. I got a bit wiser and found a solution. If i add instance to the path it works. So i am accessing the config files relative to the root folder instead. It's confusing to me why i need to do this, since i am setting the flag `instance_relative_config`  to `True`.

Comment: I am not 100% sure how it works, but it looks only `from_pyfile` method is working for the `instance_relative_config`. There is an example of accessing the config via `app.instance_path` at the bottom of http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#config-dev-prod but this method looks a bit ad-hoc for me in terms of accessing a class.

Comment: @taras Okay, well thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After import, only the class needs to be given as a parameter.

```py
from project.instance.config import ProductionConfig


app.config.from_object(ProductionConfig)
```